# Issue serving multiple SSL certs via nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've got two domains both with SSL certs on one nginx instance. I'm trying to redirect http to https and removing www hostname on both domains i.e. http://www.site1.com redirects to https://site1.com

What I've got at the moment, http://site1.com redirects fine and issues the correct cert, however http://www.site1.com issues the SSL cert from site2.com and doesn't redirect without www. site2 works fine for all redirects and issues teh correct certs. I think it has to do with me using "default" in the SSL config for site2, however if I remove it both sites then return connection refused errors.

Here's the configs

/etc/nginx/sites-available/site1

```
upstream site1.com {
    server unix:/home/site1.com/site1.com.sock;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site1.com www.site1.com;
  return 301 https://site1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.site1.com;
    return 301 https://site1.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.com;

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    include snippets/ssl-site1.com.conf;
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/site2

```
upstream site2 {
    server unix:/home/site2/site2.sock;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site2.com www.site2.com site2.co.uk www.site2.co.uk;
  return 301 https://site2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.site2.com;
    return 301 https://site2.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site2.com;

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl default http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default http2;
    include snippets/ssl-site2.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
```

Comment: `http://www.site1.com` does not issue any certificate since it is only a HTTP connection. Did you mean `https://www.site1.com`? What is the CURL output of the request to `http://www.site1.com` and `https://site1.com`?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I'm trying to get `http://www.site1.com` to redirect to `https://site1.com`. Curl to `http://www.site1.com` is `301 moved permanently` and curl to `https://site1.com` returns the page and cert correctly

Comment: Just been doing some more research, i'm using the same IP for both domains, is this the issue as SSL doesn't play well with two virtual hosts on the same IP?

Comment: CURL for `https://www.site1.com` returns `curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (site2.com) does not match target host name 'www.site1.com'`

Answer (score 3):

You do not have certificates defined for the `www.site1.com` and `www.site2.com` server blocks so `nginx` is probably using whichever certificate was loaded first in the configuration.

Your certificates are presumably defined in the `snippets/ssl-site1.com.conf` and `snippets/ssl-site2.com.conf` files.

Assuming that your certificates are valid for the `www.` variant of the domain name, those statements need to be included in the other server blocks.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.site1.com;
    include snippets/ssl-site1.com.conf;
    return 301 https://site1.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Wish I saw this answer a few seconds earlier. I've got it working but by using letsencrypt to issue a multi-domain certificate for `site1.com` and `site2.com`. I assumed because SSL isn't meant to work well for multiple certificates/virtual hosts on one IP that a multi certificate, vs using two seperate certs, was the only way to go?

Comment: It hasn't been the only way to go for years, SSL has supported virtual hosts for a long time.